# Ajax response is null

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I have an AJAX call that talks to my Rails controller, the AJAX is okay but the callback contains no data.

My AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/get_progress/:' + this.props.myfile,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error");
    }.bind(this)
});
```

My rails controller method:

```
def get_progress
    a = Rails.configuration.progress
    render :text => a
end
```

My routes:

```
get '/get_progress/:id' => 'myfiles#get_progress'
```

My AJAX Success callback has no data in it, why is my `a` value not passed back?

Comment: If you open the route directly in the browser, do you see a response then?

Comment: Yes I can see the response in the route directly.

Comment: What does js console say? Is request performed and data returned?

Comment: I’m not perfectly sure since I’m not experienced with Rails, but doesn’t the `:id` part in the route is a placeholder and actual routes then should not include the colon? So you should only call `'/get_progress/' + this.props.myfile`. If that doesn’t work, check the network tab of your browser to see what request it performs and check whether any output is returned there.

Comment: Yes, that was stupid of me. Never saw that really. Thanks. Had it working. Can you add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` is incorrect, the `:id` is meant to just be the *value* of the ID:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/get_progress/' + this.props.myfile,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});
```